# How to convert integer to text aligning the text on the left?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to convert

```
1
12
145
```

to (where I use S for SPACE)

```
SSSS1
SSS12
SS145
```

If I use `CAST (VALUE as CHAR(5))` I get

```
1SSSS
12SSS
145SS
```

How to perform that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT STR(N,5)
FROM (VALUES (1),(12),(145)) T(N)
```

Returns

```
-----
    1
   12
  145
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies (this seems a easy task) anyway I googled and stackoverflowed with no results for long before asking. I choose this as answer since it is the most compact. Anyway also the RIGHT idea is of course good.

Answer (score 2):

```
RIGHT('     ' + CAST (VALUE as VARCHAR(5)), 5)
```

More generally:

```
DECLARE @PadTo tinyint;
SET @PadTo = 5;

SELECT
     RIGHT(REPLICATE(' ', @PadTo) + CAST(VALUE as VARCHAR(255)), @PadTo)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find your ansewer here:

[SQL Padding](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/padleadingzeros/)

particularly:

```
SELECT RIGHT ('000000'+ CAST (@Number AS varchar), 6)
```

Comment: Unimpressive copy/paste. OP asked for leading spaces and length 5 though: could have made a bit more effort...

Comment: That downvote was unfair, I wanted to give a hint, giving full answer is soooo lame

Comment: I didn't down vote: your answer isn't wrong, just looks like a copy+paste.

Comment: @VoodooRider - I'm a bit baffled by your stated policy above. This is a Q & A site not a Q & H site.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @T table(Value int)

insert into @T values (1),(12),(145)

select right(stuff(Value, 1, 0, space(5)), 5)
from @T
```